# Using Interface Builder in Xcode 4.6.2

Tags: ios, xcode4, interface-builder

I have just updated my Xcode to the latest version and the IB is quite different from the version I used before. I've created some IBOutlets and whereas before I could drag from the Files Owner to the component to marry up my IBOutlet from my .h file. In the new version there are three icons one of which is the Files Owner but it doesn't seem to do anything. How do I marry up my IBOutlets in the new version?

Comment: You might want to read my book's chapter on nibs, as it is up to date: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch07.html

Comment: You have a *lot* of options for how to create an outlet: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch07.html#_more_ways_to_create_outlets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press and hold 'Ctrl' key while dragging. You'll see a blue line. Drag the blue line to the item you want to connect and when you release you'll get a popover showing your outlets.

Alternatively, show the code file and the XIB file beside each other (using the assistant editor). Each outlet definition will have a circle beside it in the trough. Drag from there and you'll get the same blue line to connect with but this time Xcode knows the outlet so it just connects it as soon as you drop on the target view.

[image]